# Error when trying to install mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

> kerberos@0.0.12 install C:\Workspace\nodeAuthv1\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\
>   kerberos> (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

C:\Workspace\nodeAuthv1\node_modules\mongoose\node_modules\mongodb\node_modules\mongodb-core\node_modules\kerberos>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\....\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild) else (rebuild)

**I tried cleaning the npm cache as someother stackoverflow answers suggested.what should i do to get rid of this error and the same error occurs for the [connect-mongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/connect-mongo) npm package also.I am new to nodejs and I dont know what is the problem.Help me out**

Comment: Have you tried running as admin? WinXX permissions are fickle and you might have a permissions issue. Also check the output log as mentioned for specific errors

Comment: yes.I am running the command prompt as admin and even tried installing
npm install -g node-gyp as other answers suggested.still not working

Comment: So what exactly is the error in `builderror.log`? If it doesn't point you to an answer then at least please add that to your question.

Comment: the builderror.log file is empty.

Comment: Are you sure it's not working? Those messages look normal to me.

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue and saw that the activity indicator in the console for npm had stopped, so I thought it was locked.  It turns out that I was just being impatient. The message you are seeing it actually normal and if you give the npm enough time it will actually complete successfully. (It took about 10 minutes in my case)